# Calling C++ function from Go with buffer as argument

Tags: c++, go, cgo

We have (for all intents and purposes) something similar to the following C++ code.

`calc.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

extern "C" {
    void doCalc(uint8_t** buffer);
}
```

`calc.cpp`

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include "calc.h"

void doCalc(uint8_t** buffer) {
    uint8_t lb[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        lb[i] = i;
    }

    *buffer = new uint8_t[256];

    std::memcpy(*buffer, lb, 256);
}
```

We need to call this method from Go, but unsure how to construct the buffer variable on the Go side to pass in (seeing as the length is unknown prior to calling - the `256` in the C++ function should be considered unknown).

Comment: C or C++? They are two *very* different languages, and might need different setup for the external calls tro be possible.

Comment: Thanks, I saw in the title I made it C, my bad. This would be C++.

Comment: There are a few problems with your C++ function: The first is that you should not use `malloc` in C++, not even for simple buffers. Use `new[]` instead; The second problem is that the argument variable `buffer` is a *local* variable within the function, and whose life-time ends when the function returns. If you want to modify the variable inside the function you either need to pass it by reference or return it; Thirdly, to even be able to call the function you need to declare it as `extern "C"`.

Comment: Ah yes (it has been a few years since I have done C++). Let me update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a slightly different example that fits your use case:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>

void print_words(int count, char** words) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        printf(words[i]);
    }
}
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    words := make([]*C.char, 2)

    words[0] = C.CString("Hello ")
    words[1] = C.CString("World\n")

    C.print_words((C.int)(len(words)), (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&words[0])))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off @Jacob Wischnat 's answer (thanks!), I was able to get it working for my example:

```go
func main() {
    cBuf := make([]*C.uint8_t, 1)

    C.doCalc((**C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&cBuf[0])))
    
    gBuf := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(cBuf[0]), 256)

    // ...
}
```